# Convert Pandas time object to string

Tags: python, pandas, list, loops, datetime

I have a list of lists `dates` containing DateTimeIndex.

```
[DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-16 22:00:00', '2016-01-16 22:15:00',
                '2016-01-16 22:30:00', '2016-01-16 22:45:00',
                '2016-01-16 23:00:00', '2016-01-16 23:15:00',
                '2016-01-16 23:30:00', '2016-01-16 23:45:00',
                '2016-01-17 00:00:00'],
               dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq=None)
...
 DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-23 21:30:00', '2016-01-23 21:45:00',
                '2016-01-23 22:00:00', '2016-01-23 22:15:00',
                '2016-01-23 22:30:00', '2016-01-23 22:45:00',
                '2016-01-23 23:00:00', '2016-01-23 23:15:00',
                '2016-01-23 23:30:00'],
```

I want to convert this list to look like this:

```
[DatetimeIndex(['Saturday 22:00:00', 'Saturday 22:15:00',
                'Saturday 22:30:00', 'Saturday 22:45:00',
                'Saturday 23:00:00', 'Saturday 23:15:00',
```

and so on. The format has to be a string and I like to keep the list of lists.
I've tried the following but does not return what I want

```
[list(zip(i.day_name(), i.time)) for i in dates]


[[('Saturday', datetime.time(22, 0)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(22, 15)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(22, 30)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(22, 45)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(23, 0)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(23, 15)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(23, 30)),
  ('Saturday', datetime.time(23, 45)),
  ('Sunday', datetime.time(0, 0))],
```

However when I try to convert `i.time` to a string it gives the following error:

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'`

Is there anyone that could help me out? That would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) with `%A` for names of days with `HH:MM:SS` times:

```
dates = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2016-01-16 22:00:00', '2016-01-16 22:15:00',
                          '2016-01-16 22:30:00', '2016-01-16 22:45:00',
                          '2016-01-16 23:00:00', '2016-01-16 23:15:00',
                          '2016-01-16 23:30:00', '2016-01-16 23:45:00',
                          '2016-01-17 00:00:00'])

out = [i.strftime('%A %H:%M:%S') for i in dates]
print (out)
['Saturday 22:00:00', 'Saturday 22:15:00', 'Saturday 22:30:00', 
 'Saturday 22:45:00', 'Saturday 23:00:00', 'Saturday 23:15:00', 
 'Saturday 23:30:00', 'Saturday 23:45:00', 'Sunday 00:00:00']
```